# Pass session variable in the DataNavigateUrlFormatString for datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, c#-2.0

I am using Datagrid with a hyperlink column.

```
    <asp:DataGrid ID="dg" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" Font="Trebuchet MS, 14.25pt" Width ="880px"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" ForeColor="Black" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="LightGray"
                OnItemDataBound="dgdatabound" EnableViewState="true">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
                <ItemStyle CssClass="GridItem" />
                <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="GridAltItem" />
                <PagerStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkColumn  DataTextField ="BugId"   HeaderText="BugId" HeaderStyle-Width ="60" 
                    DataNavigateUrlField ="BugId" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SOME URL?USER"
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="AliceBlue" />
    </Columns>
```

From the above code, How can I pass 'USER' value from Session.

As of now i have tried with:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SOME URL?USER =<% Session["username"]%>"
```

but it didnt worked :(

Comment: What code have you written so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: @Dipesh Why you need to pass session variable value in URL? you can use this session variable value anywhere in your page.

Comment: @Dipesh What do you mean "it didnt worked"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ASP.NET inline expressions in properties of server controls.

See [this MSDN artcle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112):

> Remember that the displaying expression cannot be used in the
>   attributes of server controls. This is because the .NET Framework
>   directly compiles the whole expression instead of the displaying
>   content as the value to the attribute.

You will need to set this value in your code page, if you absolutely need to get it from the Session.

It's kind of hacky, but you could do it like this (probably in your Page_Load):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string yourURL = "SOME URL?USER=" + Session["username"].ToString();
        dg.Columns[0].DataNavigateUrlFormatString = yourURL;
    }
}
```

Note: the only reason I say "kind of hacky" is that you have to hardcode the column ordinal (number), which is fragile (if your column order changes).